# Cannot push dateTime data into Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, date-fns

This is the data that is console.log(values).

```
city: "abc"
departmentId: "humanResources"
email: "123@gmail.com"
facebook: ""
fullName: "afdasf"
gender: "male"
hireDate: Fri Aug 06 2021 21:30:00 GMT+0630 (Myanmar Time) {}
__proto__: Object
isPermanent: true
mobile: "65689189789"
otherDepartment: ""
university: "abcde"
__proto__: Object
```

But when I push the data into firebase, I get all the other data except for the hireDate. I use DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns" react library for getting the date. Here is the data from the firebase.

```
city: "abc"
departmentId: "humanResources"
email: "123@gmail.com"
facebook: ""
fullName: "afdasf"
gender: "male"
isPermanent: true 
mobile: "65689189789"
otherDepartment: ""
university: "abcde"
```

Comment: Explanation below. If you're having a hard time translating that to working code, edit your question to show the code that you currently use to get the `values` that you log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick glance it looks like your `hireDate` property is a `Date` object. While that is a valid JavaScript object, it is **not** a valid JSON object and Firebase Realtime Database can only store JSON objects.

The idiomatic way to solve this is by storing the timestamp of the data, which is the number of milliseconds since the epoch. You can get this value from a `Date` by calling the [`getTime()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) on it.